# How to load animated gif before Flash load

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I cannot get animated gif to display before flash movie loads. I am using this script but does not seem to work. I do not want to use a flash loader.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://www.hmaimages.com/MN/flash_loader/loading.gif';

</script>
```

Any help be much appreciated.

Comment: Where in relation to the `<script>` tag for your flash movie is this script in the html?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to show a gif in place (instead) of the  Flash until the swf file is loaded, since the browser will load, execute and render the Flash Player instantly, before the swf file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this.

Simply wrap and flash file in a `div` and give it a background image:

`div {background:url(loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}`